# Novacode docx header replacetext issue

Tags: header, novacode-docx

I'm trying to replace text in a header and it's not working.

Replacetext is working through the main body of the document.

When I look at the locals I can see this error: "'Novacode.DocX.Headers.get returned.first.Sections' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks, 
 Lbob

Answer (score 0):

It will help if i can see your code but i guees i can try to help you somehow.

This is how i replace [tag] by something, in a header :

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"docs\myDoc.docx"))
{
    document.Headers.first.ReplaceText("[tag]", "something");
}
```

Hope this will help